# Homogenous Hermitian form on the KLR algebra

Tags: hecke-algebras, hermitian, klr-algebras

Does there exist a homogenous conjugate-linear automorphism of the KLR algebra?  I want to be able to define a homogenous Hermitian form on the (Specht) modules of the (cyclotomic) KLR algebra.